# Security in token auth when using other provider authentications services such as Soundcloud?

Tags: security, authentication, soundcloud, session-storage, http-token-authentication

User Login Process by Soundcloud Connect button

1. Press the button on the website and start a session with random token generated by api server without authenticating of the user on Soundcloud.
2. User is redirect to the Soundcloud authentication page(soundcloud login page).
3. User should enter the his/her Soundcloud account information.
4. After pressing connect, a method invoked in the api side to create the user and its authentication according to the params send from SoundCloud. And api server redirects user to home page and the script in clientside sets the token to the headers as authorization to the website.

Now, my concern is starting the session before the user connects through the soundcloud, even thought users can't enter the home page without connecting to the SoundCloud.

Is this technique of authenticating user secure or not? what are the potential attacks?

Comment: This question would be a better fit for: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This approach will make you vulnerable to session fixation.

The attack scenario looks like this:

1. Attacker tricks user into using a known session key (usually through other vulnerabilities such as XSS)
2. The user authenticates with SoundCloud, the session key remains intact
3. The attacker connects to your application with the same session key, thus taking over the session.

While this is attack is not extremely common, it appears in the wild and standard procedure is to always issue a new session key after any authentication takes place.